# How to use Prop from UTT in Agda

Tags: agda, dependent-type

In Ulf Norell's thesis he mentions that Agda is based on Luo's UTT. However, I can't find a way to use Prop there. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Prop universe was available in an early version of Agda, but it has since been removed. In fact, `Prop` is still a keyword in Agda, but using it gives an error `Prop is no longer supported`. Depending on what you want to achieve, you have a few options:

- You may want to take a look at Agda's [proof irrelevance](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.Irrelevance) feature.
- I have seen some people use the synonym `Prop = Set`. This is useful if you want to make a logical difference between propositions and more general sets, but of course it doesn't give you any of the additional axioms of `Prop`.
- Finally, there is the type of (homotopy) propositions from HoTT, which can be defined in Agda by `hProp = Σ[ X ∈ Set ] ((x y : X) → x ≡ y)`. This guarantees that propositions have at most one proof, but can cause quite some overhead.